# How to serialize a custom class with YamlDotNet

Tags: yamldotnet

I'm trying to serialize a custom class with YamlDotNet library.
Here is my class:

```cs
public class Person
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    public Person(string first, string last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
}
```

And here is how I tried to serialize it:

```cs
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("Test.txt");
Person person = new Person("toto", "titi");
Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, person);
```

But in my output file, I only have this : `{ }`

What did I forget to do to serialize my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of YamlDotNet is to serialize public properties and to ignore fields. The easiest fix is to replace the public fields with automatic properties:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public Person(string first, string last)
    {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
    }
}
```

You could alter the behavior of YamlDotNet to serialize private fields relatively easily, but I do not recommend that.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. But what if I don't want to serialize all my properties, there is a way to "hide" them from YamlDotNet ?

Comment: Nevermind, I find the answer to my question. If someone else is looking for the answer, you have to add the attribute YamlIgnore to your properties.
Thanks again for the help

Comment: "Default behavior" implies that some type of non-default behavior is supported. In this case it's hard-coded, fixed behavior. It seems reasonable to support (at least optionally) serializing public fields.

Comment: There is support for replacing this behavior, by providing a different implementation of the interface `ITypeInspector`. So yes, the default behavior is to consider only public properties, but you can implement any behavior you want.