# How to convert JSON to YAML using YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, json, yaml, yamldotnet

I am trying to convert JSON to YAML using YamlDotNet. This is the code I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"UberAPI\",\"description\":\"MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"host\":\"api.uber.com\",\"schemes\":[\"https\"],\"basePath\":\"/v1\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\"]}";
        var swaggerDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, swaggerDocument);
            var yaml = writer.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(yaml);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the JSON I provide:

```
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "title":"UberAPI",
      "description":"MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI",
      "version":"1.0.0"
   },
   "host":"api.uber.com",
   "schemes":[
      "https"
   ],
   "basePath":"/v1",
   "produces":[
      "application/json"
   ]
}
```

This is the YAML I expect:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: UberAPI
  description: MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI
  version: 1.0.0
host: api.uber.com
schemes:
  - https
basePath: /v1
produces:
  - application/json
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
swagger: []
info:
  title: []
  description: []
  version: []
host: []
schemes:
- []
basePath: []
produces:
- []
```

I don't have a clue why all properties are empty arrays.

I also tried typed deserialization and serialization like this:

```
var specification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwaggerDocument>(json);
...
serializer.Serialize(writer, swaggerDocument, typeof(SwaggerDocument));
```

But that produces

```
{}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is not necessarily helpful: YAML seems to be unpopular (outside of Ruby). Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: My client has a requirement that my API exposes its specification in both JSON as well as YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is problem when json deserialization returns `JObject`. Looks like yaml serializer doesn't like it.

I used deserialization with specified type as you mentioned `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwaggerDocument>(json)` and this is what I get

```
Swagger: 2.0
Info:
  Title: UberAPI
  Description: MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI
  Version: 1.0.0
Host: api.uber.com
Schemes:
- https
BasePath: /v1
Produces:
- application/json
```

This is my whole code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{\"Swagger\":\"2.0\",\"Info\":{\"Title\":\"UberAPI\",\"Description\":\"MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI\",\"Version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"Host\":\"api.uber.com\",\"Schemes\":[\"https\"],\"BasePath\":\"/v1\",\"Produces\":[\"application/json\"]}";
        var swaggerDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwaggerDocument>(json);
        
        var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, swaggerDocument);
            var yaml = writer.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(yaml);
        }
    }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class SwaggerDocument
{
    public string Swagger { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public List<string> Schemes { get; set; }
    public string BasePath { get; set; }
    public List<string> Produces { get; set; }
}
```

**update**

Two issues here.

When deserializing class with fields, by default, `json.net` won't take them into consideration when doing this job. For this purpose we have to customize the deserialization process by creating a custom contract resolver. We can easily do this by

```
var swaggerDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwaggerDocument>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver()
});

public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
            .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)))
            .ToList();
        props.ForEach(p => { p.Writable = true; p.Readable = true; });
        return props;
    }
}
```

There is second issue when we want to serialize class with fields: Values from fields won't be included into yaml result. I haven't figured out how to deal with this yet.

Do you have to use `Swashbuckle.Swagger` type or you can just create wrapper/decorator/DTO for this type?

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It has helped me find the problem: apparently, `YamlDotNet` doesn't like fields. I tried your code: works like a charm. I converted the properties of your classes to fields (as the [real SwaggerDocument](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerDocument.cs) has) and the output becomes `{}`. Haven't found a solution for this new problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I could wrap the Swashbuckle classes but that's far from ideal. I'd be happier with a custom `ITypeInspector` as described in the comments of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28456466/502395) but I haven't found a way to insert it in the serializer.

Comment: I checked `YamlDotNet` and I couldn't find place where we can plug custom implementation of `ITypeInspector` :/

Comment: Me neither. Thanks for helping me anyway.

Answer (score 18):

You don't actually need to deserialize JSON into strongly typed object you can convert JSON to YAML using dynamic Expando object as well. Here is a small example:-

```
var json = "{
        'Name':'Peter',
        'Age':22,
        'CourseDet':{
                'CourseName':'CS',
                'CourseDescription':'Computer Science',
                },
        'Subjects':['Computer Languages','Operating Systems']
        }";

var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, expConverter);

var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();
var yaml = serializer.Serialize(deserializedObject);
```

You can see a detailed explanation of both methods, i.e., using strongly typed object and dynamic object, [here](http://getgoingit.blogspot.in/2016/12/json-to-yaml-conversion-for-net.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the `JObject` to a simpler object that YamlDotNet can serialize:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"UberAPI\",\"description\":\"MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"host\":\"api.uber.com\",\"schemes\":[\"https\"],\"basePath\":\"/v1\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\"]}";
        var swaggerDocument = ConvertJTokenToObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json));

        var serializer = new YamlDotNet.Serialization.Serializer();

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, swaggerDocument);
            var yaml = writer.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(yaml);
        }
    }

    static object ConvertJTokenToObject(JToken token)
    {
        if (token is JValue)
            return ((JValue)token).Value;
        if (token is JArray)
            return token.AsEnumerable().Select(ConvertJTokenToObject).ToList();
        if (token is JObject)
            return token.AsEnumerable().Cast<JProperty>().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => ConvertJTokenToObject(x.Value));
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected token: " + token);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for parsing nested objects - See Example 5
http://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I wrote a nuget library to make YamlDotNet work great with Json.Net, honoring all of the JSON.net serialization attributes.

- Github: https://github.com/tomlm/YamlConvert
- Nuget library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlConvert/

```
    var yaml = YamlConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var obj2 = YamlConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(yaml);
```

It works by adding a YamlDotNet type serialization class for JTokens (JObject/JArray/JValue)

```
    var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
         .WithTypeConverter(new JTokenYamlConverter())
         .Build();
```

Comment: i wrote some code like this
 ```
    public static string JsonToYaml(this string json)
    {
        var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
            .WithTypeConverter(new JTokenYamlConverter())
            .Build();

        return YamlConvert.YamlConvert.SerializeObject(json, serializer);
    }
```

return still json, any wrong with me?
https://i.imgur.com/fJD3wuB.png

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting with a JSON string, as the OP has, and you want idiomatic YAML output, it's worth noting that JSON *is* valid YAML, so YamlDotNet can load it directly, then a simple visitor can adjust the "style" before writing it back out.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using YamlDotNet.Core;
using YamlDotNet.Core.Events;
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;

public static void Main()
{
    var json = "{\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"UberAPI\",\"description\":\"MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"host\":\"api.uber.com\",\"schemes\":[\"https\"],\"basePath\":\"/v1\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\"]}";
    var yaml = new YamlStream();
    yaml.Load(new StringReader(json));
    yaml.Accept(new JsonToYamlConverterVisitor());
    var outputYaml = new StringWriter();
    yaml.Save(outputYaml, false);
    outputYaml.Flush();
    var yamlString = outputYaml.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(yamlString);
}

class JsonToYamlConverterVisitor : YamlVisitorBase
{
    public override void Visit(YamlScalarNode scalar)
    {
        if (scalar.Style == ScalarStyle.DoubleQuoted && (scalar.Value == "null" || scalar.Value == "true" || scalar.Value == "false"))
            scalar.Style = ScalarStyle.DoubleQuoted;
        else scalar.Style = ScalarStyle.Plain;
        base.Visit(scalar);
    }

    public override void Visit(YamlSequenceNode sequence)
    {
        sequence.Style = SequenceStyle.Block;
        base.Visit(sequence);
    }

    public override void Visit(YamlMappingNode mapping)
    {
        mapping.Style = MappingStyle.Block;
        base.Visit(mapping);
    }
}
```

which outputs

```yaml
swagger: 2.0
info:
  title: UberAPI
  description: MoveyourappforwardwiththeUberAPI
  version: 1.0.0
host: api.uber.com
schemes:
- https
basePath: /v1
produces:
- application/json
...
```

Run this example on DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YUJjzQ

Answer (score 0):

```
var serializer = new SharpYaml.Serialization.Serializer();
var yaml = serializer.Deserialize(jObject.ToString());
return serializer.Serialize(yaml);
```

YAML supports JSON deserialization, therefor you can either convert the JObject to a string or just give the serializer your JSON directly without using JObject.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the following piece of code to build a Yaml element from a JSON and writing it to a file.

Here is the code:

```
    public static void BuildParametrizedYAML(string element, string element1)
    {
        var jsonBreakers = @"
        {
            'watchers' : {
                'timer' : '10',
                'watcherPool' : '5',
                's3fileExtension' : '.avr.gz',
                'maxRetriesTask' : '3',
                'telemetryFolder' : '/data',
                'telemetryProcessor' : { 
                    'url' : '"+ element1 + @"'
                },
                'breakers' : 
                [
                    {
                        'breakerId' : 'COMMANDER',
                        'firstRetryTimeout' : '1000',
                        'secondRetryTimeout' : '6000',
                        'retries' : '5'
                    },
                    {
                        'breakerId' : 'PROCESSOR',
                        'firstRetryTimeout' : '1000',
                        'secondRetryTimeout' : '6000',
                        'retries' : '30'
                    }
                ],
                'servers' : 
                [
                    {
                        'serverId' : 'vmax',
                        'url' : '"+ element + @"'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }";

        var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonBreakers, expConverter);           
        var serializer = new Serializer();
        string JSONContent = serializer.Serialize(deserializedObject);

        var streamLoad = new StringReader(JSONContent);
        var stream = new YamlStream();
        stream.Load(streamLoad);

        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("application.yml"))
        {
            stream.Save(writer, false);
        }
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
watchers:
  timer: 10
  watcherPool: 5
  s3fileExtension: .avr.gz
  maxRetriesTask: 3
  telemetryFolder: /data
  telemetryProcessor:
    url: TELEMETRYPROCESSORURL
  breakers:
  - breakerId: COMMANDER
    firstRetryTimeout: 1000
    secondRetryTimeout: 6000
    retries: 5
  - breakerId: PROCESSOR
    firstRetryTimeout: 1000
    secondRetryTimeout: 6000
    retries: 30
  servers:
  - serverId: vmax
    url: TELEMETRYWATCHERVMAXURL
...
```

Feel free to write me about this.